# Prettier autosaving (esbenp.prettier-vscode) conflict with prettier/prettier rule

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, typescript-eslint

I want to use ESLint along with Prettier. Everything is fine except when I press Ctrl + S to save the file, Prettier changes file in a way which is not compatible with `prettier/prettier` rule in ESLint.

Content of `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "prettier.printWidth": 70,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "eslint.codeAction.showDocumentation": {
    "enable": true
  },
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript"]
}
```

Content of `.eslint.json`:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": ["google", "prettier"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"]
  }
}
```

I know if I remove `"editor.formatOnSave": true,` from `settings.json` all of problems get resolved but I don't like the saved format because lines of code are too long and I like to break long line into multiple line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Prettier is using `printWidth` of 70 characters but ESlint have a `max-len` of 80 characters.
You should modify one of them to keep them sync, e.g. you can change `printWidth` inside `settings.json` to make Prettier compatible with ESlint(`"prettier.printWidth": 80`).
Content of `./vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "prettier.printWidth": 80,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "eslint.codeAction.showDocumentation": {
    "enable": true
  },
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript"]
}
```